# Switching from eevee to cycles causes objects to "melt"

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine

creating a small bedroom scene and changed from eevee to cycles to see how it look from there, when my objects started to "melt" (see image)[image: Eevee vs Cycles]
notes: using Poliigon, and version 3.3

Comment: hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/RlW60Ygw is the object, and it also happens with other models in the scene

Answer (score 2):

Unplug the *Displacement* node:

[image]

Or choose the *Bump Only* option in the *Material panel > Settings > Surface > Displacement*. I can't test as you didn't pack the images but the *Displacement* node displaces the topology if you set it to *Displacement*, and it only works in Cycles.

[image]

Comment: It seems to work for the model uploaded, however i encountered the same issue with a seperate model linked here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/614EgjPy and the fix doesnt seem to work

Comment: Exact same problem, just make sure that you select the good material in the Material panel (the one that is used for these faces of the object), then unplug

Comment: also don't forget to `tab` into *Edit Mode* and press `a` then `m` *> Merge By Distance* which will eliminate 1486 duplicate overlapping vertices.